# Latex Stylesheet and inline text cells

Tags: stylesheet, latex

I am looking for a professionally looking LaTex ish stylesheet, where i can still calculate equations within Mathematica.

Also i am wondering if i can get inlineText cells to display summations with limits from limits being at the side to above/under the sigma sign. See picture below.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

BR
Mads